# Why doesn't roundf work for me in this case?

Tags: c, math, rounding

This is C. I am a beginner, so sorry for the experts to whom this question may seem trivial. I am trying to round this float to the nearest integer, away from zero. I've also tried rintf based on some other posts on the internet, but it just won't work! I used printf to check the results, and they weren't rounded to the nearest integer.

```
//Approximate US grade level.
float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;

float roundf(float index);
```

Comment: Your question is missing critical parts: 1) how `roundf` is used/called 2) how you print the result and conclude. Post a [mcve].

Comment: "but it just won't work! " lacks needed details.  Post a [mcve]. " used printf to check the results, and they weren't rounded to the nearest integer." talks about the how, but code would be better.  IAC, sample data is needed too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
float roundf(float index);
```

is a declaration of a function. It is not a call.

If you use `float roundf(float index);` as function call inside of `index = float roundf(float index);` you should get a compiler error, but maybe you are on an uncommon compiler. Thus it can be a reason that it "won't work" as expected.

A correct call would be `index = round(index);`.

> I used printf to check the results, and they weren't rounded to the nearest integer.

Note that floating-point precision [isn't the best one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004) in case you want to represent integers with it. A `float` or `double` can't represent an even integer value fully accurate. It has only a narrowed and limited precision.

Related:

- [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/)

Comment: "A float or double can't represent an integer precisely/accurately." is unclear.  `float` and `double` certainly represent integers +/- 2^24 exactly.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Was already at an edit as you commented. :-)

Comment: OP's formula [`0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman–Liau_index) certainly has nothing to do with currency.  Unclear why a link to "Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Exactly, but his/her expectation maybe: "I used printf to check the results, and they weren't rounded *to the nearest integer*"

Comment: There may be a deeper underlying issue in the code that needs to be addressed. The OP wrote(coded) `float roundf (float index)` which is the function header. I think someone needs to explain that syntax for calling a function differs from syntax of function header

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Well spotted! But a legit compiler would throw an error in this case and OP said s/he is be able to run the code. But this is also why I voted to close the question, too. I took it into the answer, thank you.

Comment: "But a legit compiler would throw an error in this case" --> err, no.  OK to declare functions in a function.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I meant an assignment like that `index = float roundf(float index);`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in C take an input and return an output in this way: `output = function(input);`. There may be more than one input for some functions, of course, but the principle is that.

For your case, try `index = roundf(index);` if you want the result to overwrite the non-rounded value.